# uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut returns less value of token B than present in reverses

Tags: ethereum, web3js, hardhat, uniswap

I have the next code to get familiar with uniswap mechanics:

- create pair contract
- get reserves
- invoke `getAmountsOut` and provide all UNI token reserves

```
  const pairAddress = await _V2Factory.getPair(uniToken, wethToken);
  const pairContract = new ethers.Contract(
    pairAddress,
    IUniswapV2Pair.abi,
    _provider
  );
  const tmpReserves = await pairContract.getReserves();
  const reserves = [reserves.reserve0, reserves.reserve1];
  console.log("reserves", reserves);

  const output = await router.getAmountsOut(reserves[0], [
    uniToken.address,
    wethToken.address,
  ]);
  console.log("output", output);
```

Output is:

- reserves: `[ 36851089197799104779745113323n, 281312509765248795074n ]`
- output: `[ 36851089197799104779745113323n, 140444953548298972803n ]`

The question is why I do not receive as the second element of `output` array equals to `281312509765248795074n` - the full `WETH` liquidity in pair but just part of liquidity equals to `140444953548298972803n` value?

I'm running local hardhat node and 3-rd parties actions should not affect the result. I tried on mainnet as well, obviously results are the same.

Tried also switch from `getAmountsOut` to `getAmountOut`, but it behaves the same way:

```
const output2 = await router.getAmountOut(
    reserves[0],
    reserves[0],
    reserves[1]
  );
  console.log("output2", output2);
```

output: `143271499822164119007n`

Comment: What makes you think it should return the value of B present in reserves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniswap and other constant product automated market makers (AMM) use the following invariant for each pool:

[image]

Where `x` and `y` are the amounts of the tokens in the pool and `k` is a constant.

The function `getAmountsOut` simulates a trade in the pool. After any trade, `x` and `y` changes, but the invariant still holds:

[image]

If you call `getAmountsOut` with `x` as the parameter, you essentially ask (ignoring the swap fees for a moment) "how much `y` would I get if I doubled `x` in the pool?" Then `x' = 2x` and the invariant is:

[image]

Solving it for `y'` you get `y' = y / 2` balances in the pool. The expected output from this trade is `y - y'`, which is again equal to  `y / 2` and approximately matches your output. Incidentally, this trade would also push up the price in the pool 4 times, since price is defined as `y/x`.

In the real code, the result is slightly different, since:

1. A 0.3% fee is first subtracted from the input amount `x` before the trade is made.
2. There are some inevitable rounding errors, which may further reduce the exact number of tokens bought.